# How to sort list view by dates descending, but with blank dates on top?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list-view

I have a list of tasks and those tasks have a "Planned Release Date" which is sometimes blank. I want the most future tasks at the top... but that means the blank ones all get sorted to the bottom.

Is there a way to specify that "blank" should sort to the top?